# Select CollectionViewCell when scrolled into view

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a collection view that is 100 points wide with a number of cells that are each also 100 points wide.  I've got it setup to support scrolling and paging horizontally so the user can flick left and right and each cell occupies the entire collection view frame.

Originally, I had no scrolling and the user would tap each cell to activate something in the app.  Now that its a narrow frame where only one cell can be seen at a time I feel that tapping is redundant and the cell should simply be tapped in effect when it comes in view.

Is there a way to trigger an event such as `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` when a given `UICollectionViewCell` becomes the one displayed within my collection view's frame?

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionView` responds to [selectItemAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/selectItemAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:).

It also responds to [indexPathsForVisibleItems](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/indexPathsForVisibleItems) which will be useful to determine where to make the selection.

You also need to decide *when* to make the selection, probably best after receiving [scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:) which the delegate inherits from `UIScrollViewDelegate`).

But it may be even better advice to look at what your code does upon selection and just do that (launched from the same place in code, probably when scrolling is finished), leaving selection out of it.

Comment: `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` doesn't get called when my collection view ends scrolling.  what i need is a callback when it stops scrolling that doesn't get in an infinite loop.  for example, i can use `willDisplayCell:` that gets called with the correct indexpath of the currently in focus cell every time scrolling stops.  But by calling `didSelectAtIndexPath` directly in that callback you get an infinite loop and a crash.  I DO need to invoke some collectionView method like didSelect and not simply run generic app logic code because the cell needs to go into its highlighted mode.

Comment: Oh.  Sorry, the method (for user initiated scrolls) is `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`.   Please see edit.  Also please make sure your VC is the collection view's delegate.

Comment: of course i've set my delegate.  the problem is what I really wish i could do is directly invoke `didSelect` in whatever callback i get when ending scrolling.  i believe `didEndDecelerating` should not result in an infinite loop as it isn't retriggered by `didSelect` in the way that `willDisplayCell` does..  the problem i can see with `didEndDecelerating` is it doesn't have an indexpath as a parameter so how can i determine which cell to activate?

Comment: so i think it boils down to me needing a callback when scrolling ends.. that a) contains the indexpath of the current cell .. but b) doesn't get re-called when reloadData is called